# Drawing a circle in Matlab

Tags: matlab, draw, geometry

I tried to draw a filled circle in Matlab and faced a problem.
There is a way to write something like this:

```
plot(x, y, 'o', ...
    'MarkerEdgeColor', 'r', ...
    'MarkerFaceColor', 'r', ...
    'MarkerSize', 200)
```

But I need to draw a circle with size in measurement of the scales, not in points. I haven't found a special function, so I made it on my own:

```
hold on;

rad = 2;
center = [1, 1];

theta = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 5000);
for i = 1:numel(theta)
    x = rad * cos(theta(i)) * [1, 1];
    y = rad * sin(theta(i)) * [-1, 1];
    plot(center(1) + x, center(2) + y, 'black');
end
```

The 'quality' of this circle depends on number of intervals. In my program I need to draw a lot of them so it it extremely slow process of compilation.

Comment: You can color in the shape with the `FaceColor` parameter to `rectangle` per [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html#busopj9-5).

Comment: @TroyHaskin omg, thank you! I cant understand how did I miss this function!

Comment: Well, it is a little odd that the easiest builtin for drawing a circle is `rectangle`.  (^_^)